# Should you offer users an option to clear their basket themselves?

Tags: e-commerce

We're looking at adding this functionality to our basket to allow users to clear all products in their basket. Is this standard practice or is a 'Save for later' button or wish list function a better approach?

Comment: Could you explain why you don't want users to be able to clear their shopping basket? Omitting the functionality would likely score poorly in a task where users are asked to remove items from the basket, which is a common real-world activity.

Answer (score 3):

If the user is in their basket then this would be one of the functionalities users currently expect.

In the basket allow the user to:

- change qty of their items
- see the number and qty of items in the
  basket
- see the sub-total of their items
- and, if you have their shipping
  address, it would be nice to have an "estimated tax" summary
- Since users expect to be able to remove items from their shopping cart having a one-click option is an excellent idea.

And then, obviously, allow them to return to the shopping area, and continue through the purchasing process.